# dojo 1.8 setFocusCell() not working properly in ie 11

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer, dojo

"I am using dojo enhanced grid. If I click on any editable cell then after editing when I press enter or up/down arrow keys then the focus should go to the next cell below it & it should be in edit mode, tab also not working in IE11.
The code which I have used works in IE10,IE9 properly. Below is the code snippet which I have used."

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("gridDiv"), "keydown", function(event) {        
    var pagesString = ($('.dojoxGridActivedSwitch').attr('title')).split(' ');
    var page = pagesString[0];        
        switch(event.keyCode) {
            case keys.UP_ARROW:     
                if (event.rowIndex != 0) {
                    gridDiv.focus.setFocusCell(event.cell, (event.rowIndex) - 1);
                } 
                break;
            case keys.DOWN_ARROW:                
                  if (event.rowIndex != page-1) {
                    gridDiv.focus.setFocusCell(event.cell, (event.rowIndex)+ 1);
                } 
                break;
            case keys.ENTER:
                event.preventDefault();              

                if(event.target.type !== "submit") {
                    if (event.rowIndex != page-1) {
                        gridDiv.focus.setFocusCell(event.cell, (event.rowIndex)+ 1);
                    } 
                } 
                break;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about this but I had faced the same issue, I updated library from 1.8.0 to 1.8.6 and it started working properly for IE 11. Try to do the same I think this is same issue